Binomial theorem for ideals
I was proving the statement that if $I$ and $J$ solvable ideals of Lie algebra $L$, then $I + J$ is a solvable ideal of $L$.
The proof is we know $$(I+J)/J\cong I/I\cap J.$$ Since $I,J$ are solvable then so is $I\cap J$ and hence $I/I\cap J$ and so $I+J$.
But can there be another proof?
I was thinking, if ideals follow binomial theorem, then $(I+J)^{(m+n+1)}=0$ if $I^{(m)}=0,J^{(n)}=0$.
So do ideals follow binomial theorem? If yes, then would the above idea be correct?

Indeed, this is true, because
$$
(I+J)^{(m+n)}\subseteq I^{(m)}+J^{(n)}
$$
for all $m,n\ge 0$. The proof is given in Jacobson's book, and works the same for nilpotent ideals. Because each term in $(I+J)^{(m+n)}$ will either lie in $I^{(m)}$, or $J^{(n)}$, depending on whether there are at least $m$ terms from $I$, or at least $n$ terms from $J$.
For $m,n$ big enough it follows that $I^{(m)}=J^{(n)}=0$, since both $I$ and $J$ are solvable. Hence $I+J$ is solvable.

Oh great! Thank you
